# Как выстроить меню в адаптиве в колонку при помощи флекс-боксов?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

при нажатии на бургер вылезает меню и я хочу,чтобы оно располагалось посередине экрана в колонку. Пробовал задать display: flex и flex-direction: column родителю, но не выходит.`введите сюда код` https://jsfiddle.net/s8bv9Le6/
[image: 123]

Answer (score 0):

Не срабатывает display: flex потому-что ты навешиваешь тегу ul через скрипт display: block; в атрибуте style.
Задай всем своим li внутри ul display: inline-block;

```
nav ul li { 
 display: inline-block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

Comment: я не нашел у себя в коде,где я вешаю на ul скрипт display: block и зачем мне прописывать  display: inline-block всем li,если мне надо выстроить в колонну,а не в линию?

Comment: Так [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtq4oLy7/2/)?